# Python Chosing To Ignore String Value

Tags: python, string

Using Python v2, is there a way to ignore a value in a string if it is there?

For instance: I want someone to enter a value of $100.00, or they could enter a value of 100.00 without the leading $ symbol. What I want to do is ignore the '$' value if it is typed in.

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
s = "  $100.00 "
f = float(s.strip().lstrip("$"))
```

The `.strip()` strips whitespace from the beginning and the end of the string, and the `.lstrip("$")` strips a dollar sign from the beginning, if present.

Comment: Thanks for the `lstrip`, I did not know about that either

Answer (score 1):

Just filter out unwanted characters from the string. There are multiple ways of doing this, for clarity you could use:

```
def clean(s, wanted = "0123456789."):
  """Returns version of s without undesired characters in it."""
  out = ""
  for c in s:
    if c in wanted:
      out += c
  return out
```

To avoid the dynamic string-building, which is costly, you can build a list and then turn the list into a string:

```
def clean2(s, wanted = "0123456789."):
  outlist = [c for c in s if c in wanted]
  return "".join(outlist)
```

Comment: Extending a string using addition is tremendously slow and should be avoided at all costs. It's much better to add the characters to a list then use "".join(out) to turn it into a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to remove a '$' then `s.replace('$', '')` will do want you want.

If you want to replace more than one character then you need to chain replace calls together, which gets very ugly very quickly and in that case one of the other solutions is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a regular expression to extract the number from the string.

Or your could be lazy if you just want to remove a leading `$`:

```
if s.startswith('$'):
    s = s[1:]
```

If you want to remove multiple `$` signs, replace `if` with `while` or use `s = s.lstrip('$')`

PS: You might want to remove trailing `$` signs, too. `rstrip()` or `endswith()` and `s[:-1]` are your friends in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just [lstrip](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) `$` from the string before you process it.

```
value = ...
value = value.lstrip( ' $' ) # Strip blank and $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "$100.00"
b = ''.join((c for c in a if c != "$"))
```

of course this is reasonable if you don't know the position of the character you want to remove